# Activating warning throw for any NaN or INF observed in a Matlab code

Tags: matlab, warnings, nan

I am seeing a bug in output of my Matlab code. The reason should be that somewhere in a function some variable becomes NaN. But I receive no warning anywhere. How can I make Matlab give warning on every little arithmetic anomaly, in particular NaN or Inf, so that I can recover the line number that problem happens.

The warning is on now.
Are there other settings that control this?

Comment: Some example code would be useful with the bug or 'anomaly'.

Comment: I.e. NaN, inf, overflow, underflow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write

```
dbstop if naninf
```

in the command window. See [`dbstop` documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html) for more options.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you can add `if` conditions for your input (call it `m`) that will give you a warning, for example:

```
if any(isnan(m))
   warning('Input has NaN value')
end

if any(isinf(m))
   warning('Input has inf value')
end
...
```

read more about [`warning` in Matlab's documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/warning.html).

Comment: Sorry, I do not mean for a specific variable, I mean any variable from start of calling the function to the end of showing result.

Comment: `~isfinite(m)` will catch both cases. @user25004: I don't think there's an easy way to do what you're asking. `NaN` and `Inf` are valid floating-point values. You're going to need to [debug](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html).

Comment: Normally good practice in programming is to try to identify the places where things may start to go wrong. Here you can check that everything is alright, and otherwise throw a warning or an error. This is how matlab does, how classes are built in c++ and in java... As horchler sais, `NaN` and `Inf` are both valid floating point values, and are useful for a number of occations, so the compiler will not issue a warning. However, I also agree that debugging is the way to go here. Matlabs debug tool is one of the semplest I have encountered.

Comment: Thanks. I am using a package released by others, and somewhere in that, the data I input to it, does not behave well, I thought there should be a way to catch that. I am not debugging others' codes!

Comment: This is an example of what I am looking for. http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ug/using-fipref-objects-to-set-logging-preferences.html